# how to find all activated farm features?

Tags: powershell, feature, farm

How can I find all **activated** Farm features using PowerShell?

All **installed** Farm features can be found using:

```
Get-SPFeature -farm
```

Answer (score 1):

[this MS developer blog by Joe Rodgers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/josrod/2013/01/04/powershell-to-list-activated-features-for-a-site-and-web/) helped us with:

```
Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint2010/subsite | % {

    $results = @()

    Get-SPFeature -Web $_ -Limit All | % {

        $feature = $_; 
        $featuresDefn = (Get-SPFarm).FeatureDefinitions[$_.ID]; 
        $cc = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture;

        $obj = New-Object PSObject;
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Title  $($featuresDefn.GetTitle($cc));
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Hidden $($feature.Hidden);

        $results += $obj;
    }
    $results | FT -Auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per msdn

> The Get-SPFeature cmdlet behaves differently at each scope, returning the enabled Features at each level. If no scope is provided, all installed Features are returned

That means below command will return only active list of features

```
Get-SPFeature -Farm
```

Here is another snippet that gives the same result

```
$siteFeatures = Get-SPFeature | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "Farm" }
if ($siteFeatures -ne $null) {
    foreach ($feature in $siteFeatures) {
        if ((Get-SPFeature -Farm | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $feature.id}) -neq $null) {
       Write-Host "$($feature.Scope) feature $($feature.DisplayName) " -ForeGroundColor DarkRed
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: At first, scope Farm does not accept url as parameter in Get-Spfeature. Secondly, it only shows installed features, but not activated features.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the activated features by the **AdministrationService**

Powershell :

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::AdministrationService.Features
```

C# :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.AdministrationService.Features
```